# Excluding duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The query I'm stuck on is supposed to list the number of customers the employees sold to and count the customers only once, even if they had multiple sales. I'm very new to this and cannot seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
select count(distinct o.customerid) 'Number of Customers',
e.EmployeeID 'Employee ID', e.LastName, e.firstname
from employees e
full join Orders o
on e.EmployeeID = o.employeeid
group by o.CustomerID, e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.firstname
order by e.employeeid, o.customerid asc
```

Here are the results I'm getting, and it indicates how the list is coming up with a list of results. I'm trying to get the total number in one field. Hope this makes more sense?

[image]

Comment: Sample and expected output would help

Comment: That query looks perfectly fine, though I would suggest `left outer join`, not `full join`. You need to post your actual issue. Error? Incorrect figure?

Comment: It comes up with results, but doesn't indicate a total amount in one field, but ends up listing all the customers. I've updated my post with a screenshot of the results I'm coming up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have customerid in your group by clause - so it will produce one row per customerid - remove it (also from the orderby) and perhaps you will have the result you need

```
select count(distinct o.customerid) 'Number of Customers',
e.EmployeeID 'Employee ID', e.LastName, e.firstname
from employees e
full join Orders o
on e.EmployeeID = o.employeeid
group by  e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.firstname
order by e.employeeid
```